# Passing C# Dictionary<string,string> into TypeScript Map<string,string>

Tags: c#, reactjs, typescript

I was trying to find a best way to handle key:value pairs in TypeScript when the c# backend returns a dictionary object but anything I tried so for is not working as expected.

this is my c# code:

```
    var displayFileds = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    displayFileds.Add("A", "A Value");
    displayFileds.Add("B", "B Value");
```

this is TypeScript

```
type MyResponse = {
  displayFields: Map<string,string>
}

console.log(response.displayFields)

//sample of Map created in Typescript directly
let map = new Map([
  ["A", "A value"],
  ["B", "B value"]
]);

console.log(map)
```

I expected to see the same values for the console.log but they are absolutely different, but why? If there is no way to deserialize the object directly into a Map then what is the best way to handle Dictionaries in TypeScript?

[image]

[ Edit ]

This is how the date is being fetched from the backend(I'm using Axios):

```
const { data } = await secureAxios.post<MyResponse> 
(ApiEndpoints.GetResponse, request)
```

and the response type:

```
export type MyResponse= {
  displayFields: Map<string,string>
}
```

As you can see from the above devtools output I'm not getting back a Map<string,string> as a type suggests but rather just an object, which is not what I want

Comment: Deserialize normally into js object / array, then loop over the values to create the map

Comment: Please show us how you fetch the data from backend. Most likely, you are using a convenience generic.

Comment: JSON can only contain _object literals_. You cannot have _constructed objects_ in JSON. If you use ASP.NET to render a raw `<script>` element then you can render constructor calls, but things get gnarly.

Comment: @Lesiak I edited the question to show how i fetch from the backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Your TypeScript `type MyResponse` is wrong**:

  - By default, both `Newtonsoft.Json` (aka JSON.NET) and `System.Text.Json` will serialize `Dictionary<String,String>` to a JSON object with string-keys and string-value.

    - i.e. `interface MyResponse { readonly [key: string]: string }`
  - [JSON can only contain *object literals*](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) (i.e. some composition of JavaScript's `object` and `Array` values (expressed using `{}` and `[]` respectively), and other primitive literals (*strictly* limited to just `string` literals, `number` literals, and `true`/`false`/`null`.

    - i.e. you **cannot** invoke a JavaScript class constructor function - nor use any object/type that requires a constructed object, so referencing the `Map` type in JSON is illegal.
  - But your TypeScript `type MyResponse` uses the `Map` object, which, as mentioned above, is incorrect/wrong/illegal.

---

Possible solutions:

- If the set of dictionary keys is "static" and forms part of your web-service's "contract" then you should use a well-defined C# DTO `class` and let your JSON serializer handle it for you.

  - This is *much better* than having arbitrary and undocumented JSON object keys, and means you can use code-generation tools to automagically create web-service client-libraries for any platform out there (the web, TypeScript, Java, Rust, even [COBOL](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/fix-list-and-new-features-enterprise-cobol-zos)).

    **MyResponse.cs**

    ```cs
    public class MyResponse
    {
        [JsonConstructor]
        public MyResponse(
            [JsonProperty("displayFields")] MyResponseFields displayFields
        )
        {
            this.DisplayFields = displayFields ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(displayFields));
        }

        [JsonProperty("displayFields")]
        public MyResponseFields DisplayFields { get; }
    }

    public class MyResponseFields
    {
        [JsonConstructor]
        public MyResponseFields(
            [JsonProperty("a")] String a,
            [JsonProperty("b")] String b
        )
        {
            this.A = a;
            this.B = b;
        }

        [JsonProperty("a")]
        public String A { get; }

        [JsonProperty("a")]
        public String B { get; }
    }
    ```

    **MyResponse.ts**

    ```js
    interface MyResponseFields {
        readonly a: string;
        readonly a: string;
    }

    interface MyResponse {
        readonly displayFields: MyResponseFields;
    }
    ```
- If your `displayFields` is *always* dynamic and cannot be expressed using any kind of *static* interface (i.e. you *really do* want to send down arbitrary JSON `object` with `string` keys and `string` values), then use something like this:

  **MyResponse.cs**

  ```cs
  public class MyResponse
  {
      [JsonConstructor]
      public MyResponse(
          [JsonProperty("displayFields")] IReadOnlyDictionary<String,String> displayFields
      )
      {
          this.DisplayFields = displayFields ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(displayFields));
      }

      [JsonProperty("displayFields")]
      public IReadOnlyDictionary<String,String> DisplayFields { get; }
  }
  ```

  **MyResponse.ts**

  ```js
  interface ReadonlyStringDictionaryObject {
      readonly [key: string]: string;
  }

  interface MyResponse {
      readonly displayFields: ReadonlyStringDictionaryObject;
  }
  ```

  And used like so in TypeScript (assuming you're using `fetch`):

  ```js
  async function getMyResponse(): MyResponse {

      const resp = fetch( '/my/service/endpoint' );
      if( resp.status === 200 && resp.headers.get('Content-Type')?.startsWith('application/json') ) {
          const json = await resp.json();
          if( isMyResponse( json ) ) {
              return json;
          }
      }

      throw new Error( "something went wrong" );
  }

  function isMyResponse( obj: unknown ): obj is MyResponse {
      return (
          typeof obj === 'object' && obj !== null && 'displayFields' in obj && ( typeof ( obj as any ).displayFields === 'object' );
      );
  }

  function convertMyResponseToMap( r: MyResponse ): Map<string,string> {
      return new Map( Object.entries( r.displayFields ) );
  }

  async function doStuff() {

      const myResponse = await getMyResponse();
      const asMap      = convertMyResponseToMap( myResponse );

      console.log( asMap );
  }
  ```
- Also...

  - In JSON, object-properties (aka keys) should always be `pascalCase`, not `TitleCase`.
  - Only use TypeScript `interface` types to describe JSON responses. Avoid using `type` because that makes it easier to inadvertently use non-JSON-safe techniques and types.
  - Also, TypeScript interfaces should describe immutable objects: all properties should be `readonly`, all collections should be `readonly T[]` and so on.

    - This is a good idea because it prevents things breaking in cases where you have two or more separate consumers of the same response object - where those consumers process the same response object-graph instance sequentially, and you don't want one altering the received response object such that it would break the other consumer.

      - TypeScript's type-system [is not *entirely* "sound"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html), and data-mutations are an easy way to encounter unsound situations. Keeping things immutable makes everything else easier.
  - This extends to C# too: note how the DTO `class` definitions are all immutable, using constructors to initialize themselves with argument validation, and all properties are read-only.

    - The `[JsonConstructor]` and `[JsonProperty]` attributes on the class constructors is only needed if you intend to also deserialize the JSON from within C#.
    - If you're wondering why there's so much repetition (compared to a simpler *mutable* C# DTO class, blame the C# language designers for making custom constructors so tedious - however do consider using the new C# `record` types instead as that cuts down on a lot of tedium, but limits your ability to perform validation logic in the constructor.

Comment: Very detailed answer, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Axios uses [Convenience generic design pattern](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/generics#design-pattern-convenience-generic). You can provide the type of the response, but it is not enforced at runtime - it is equal to type assertion in terms of type safety.

Your C# backend serializes a Dictionary to following JSON string:

```json
{
   "A":"A Value",
   "B":"B Value"
}
```

which is parsed by Axios to JS object:

```javascript
{
   A: "A Value",
   B: "B Value"
}
```

This is precisely what you get logged from your response.

More generally, this means that:

- you shall specify type of the response if you trust backend to receive data in the right format
- a common trap is specifying a class as a response type - this won't work as `JSON.parse` will return a plain object, without establishing prototype chain.

You now have 2 options:

**Use returned option as is, specifying the correct type**

The correct type (matching the data actually returned from JSON.parse) is an indexed type:

```ts
type DisplayFields = {
   [key: string]: string
}
```

This is idiomatic TS, and will give you the ability to access values by key.

**Transform the result to Map**

If you rely on having a `Map` in the rest of your code:

- use the indexed type for Axios request
- transform it to a Map as soon as you receive the response.

Note:
I am not sure about the shape of your data serialized by backend - if it is only the Map or object containing the Map under the displayFields property. Modify the return type on frontend side according to shape of received data.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve the same output as `response.displayFields`, by simply using Javascript object as:

```ts
const obj = {
      A: "A value",
      B: "B value"
}
```

and the same with typescript type definition can be written as:

```ts
const obj: Record<string, string> = {
      A: "A value",
      B: "B value"
}
```

Comment: I need an interactable object I can map thru. So I need an array of key:value pairs. Not sure what are you suggesting here

Comment: @AnKing What I mentioned in the answer is an interactable  object, JavaScript objects are powerful. When we have `key` of string type, we can simply make use of JavaScript objects. Your backend response can be simply marked as of type `Record<string, string>`, which means an object having both `key` and `value` of string type, is equivalent to type `type DisplayFields = {
   [key: string]: string
} `.  Also `obj.A` is equivalent to using `map.get('A')`. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects